# Configuring Azure AD with Okta

Tags: azure-active-directory, okta

I am trying to configure Azure AD with Okta for Delegated Authentication and to Enable AD as the Profile Master. 
https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Directory/Directory_AD_Delegated_Authentication.htm
https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Directory/Directory_AD_Enable_Profile_Master.htm

I am unable to find a specific set of instructions to integrate Okta with Azure AD.
Is this something anybody can help me find or post the instructions here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this would be adding Azure AD as SAML IDP to Okta.

If you really want to use Okta AD agents, you will need Azure premium license which would allow you to use domain joined server where Okta AD agents can be installed.